# css transition of background-size in IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer, css-transitions, transition, css

is it possible to get a transition of the background-size to work in IE 10? it works fine for webkit and moz, but not for IE 10. tough the IE transitions everything else i denoted, and it also changes the background-size, but without transition.

```
a {
    background: url("../image.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

    background-size: 302px auto;
    -webkit-background-size: 302px auto;
    -moz-background-size: 302px auto;    
    -ms-background-size: 302px auto;

    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;

    height: 83px;
    margin: 0 0 0 8px;
    width: 302px;


}

a:hover {
    background-size: 324px auto;
    -webkit-background-size: 324px auto;
    -moz-background-size: 324px auto;    
    -ms-background-size: 324px auto;

    box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    height: 89px;
    margin: 9px 0 0 -4px;
    width: 324px;
}
```

thx for your help!

Comment: Is this pure css or you are using something like `less` here?

Comment: oh, sorry, yes. the .transition and .background-size are mixins. i will change it in whats behind.

Comment: By the way, there has never been an `-ms-transition`. From IE10 on the standard property is supported.

Comment: `background-size` is not an animatable property in IE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn254934(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

thanks to a friend of mine i have found another way to achieve the result i wanted. i just let the background-size on 100% and also dont change width or height; instead i resize by using transform. and transitioning the transform works even in IE10.

```
a {
    background: url("../image.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;    
    -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;

    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;

    margin: 0 0 0 8px;
    height: 83px;
    width: 302px;

}

a:hover {

    transform: scale(1.072,1.072);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.072,1.072);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.072,1.072);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.072,1.072);

    box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 8px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    margin: 9px 0 0 8px;
}
```

works also fine in opera with the -o- prefix. and in IE9 its still ok, no transition there, but everything else works.

just wanted to share, maybe someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but it seems like IE10 doesn't support background-size as a transition-property. The transition would simply fail, but it should gracefully degrade.